# C++ defining constructor make object non POD

Tags: c++, default-constructor

If I have a simple struct `Foo`, defined like this, it's a POD:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  bool c;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << (std::is_pod<Foo>::value ? "POD" : "NON POD") << '\n'; // Prints "POD"
}
```

Now imagine I want to default initalize the members and directly do:

```
struct Foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  bool c = true;
};
```

The struct is no longer a POD! Even with a constructor like this:

```
struct Foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  bool c;

  Foo() : a(0), b(0), c(false) {}
};
```

Foo has lost its PODness...

Now the tricky part begins. Imagine I want to add a constructor taking an `a`:

```
struct Foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  bool c;

  Foo(int a) : a(a), b(0), c(false) {}
};
```

Now Foo is definitely not a POD. BUT if a add a default constructor:

```
struct Foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  bool c;

  Foo() = default;
  Foo(int a) : a(a), b(0), c(false) {}
};
```

Foo is now a POD!

So as you can see, even if I simply want to use a default value like in the second example, I lose the PODness, but I can regain it as long as I define an explicit default constructor.

So the question is: should we always add a default constructor so we can benefit from the PODness of the class and improve performance? It's too bad to lose performance just because I wanted to default initialize some members...

In other words, defining default value like in the second example makes the struct non POD and non trivial, which is bad performance-wise, so how can I default initialize values and keep the struct trivial? A simple solution would be to define an `initFoo` function that returns a default initialized Foo, like for example:

```cpp
Foo initFoo() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.a = 0;
  foo.b = 1;
  foo.c = true;
  return foo;
}
```

But this is not very C++, but is it the right thing to do anyway?

Comment: There is a number of requirements a POD must satisfy. Having a trivial default constructor does not automatically make it a POD. For the most part, a `struct` is a `class`.

Comment: Why do you think that the class being POD, would increase performance? Even then: performance, of what operations, exactly? Did you profile your code, to make sure, that having your classes as POD, results in better performance, in whatever use-case you use them in?

Comment: Do note that `std::is_pod` is now (well as soon as C++20 is actually published) deprecated.  PODness is a concept that is being removed.

Comment: @Ron Of course I suppose that the rest of the struct is POD-compliant, here I am just talking about having default values.

Comment: One possible answer would be: no, you should not always add a default constructor to your classes, assuming you will benefit from POD-nes and the performance.

Comment: Are you writing on embedded system which has little resource? If yes, then PODness of your data might be concered. Or you have a data structure have to communicate to C.

Answer (score 1):

> should we always add a default constructor so we can benefit from the PODness of the class

If you want a class to be POD, then it must be trivially default constructible, among the other requirements.

One way to achieve that requirement is to not declare any constructors nor default member initialisers. Another way is to define the default constructor as default. Latter is the only way if you want the class to have any non-default constructors.

It doesn't matter which approach you pick as far as PODness is concerned.

---

> but is it the right thing to do anyway?

Your `initFoo` is a right way to return a `Foo` with specific values. Personally, I don't see value in the local variable, and would do this instead:

```
return {
    0,
    1,
    true,
};
```

Unfortunately, we lose member names from the initialisers, at least until C++20 where we can write:

```
return {
    .a = 0,
    .b = 1,
    .c = true,
};
```